# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gmaps'

Tags: python, anaconda

How to solve this problem and I have this code

```
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import pygmaps
```

But Python raises a `ModuleNotFoundError` as: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gmaps'`

I downloaded the pygmaps package in conda using this command line code `pip install git+https://github.com/thearn/pygmaps-extended`, but the error was raised once again.

Comment: do you have git installed?

Comment: try running this command `pip install gmaps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install `gmaps` from anaconda using this command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gmaps
```

or this one:

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 gmaps
```

Please enter this commands in your `conda prompt` not your OS CLI or other CLIs.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You do not have gmaps installed. install it with pip.

```
sudo pip3 install gmaps
```

And then try again with same command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem.
Anaconda Navigator has to be updated.

I have updated it, now there are no issues running in Jupyter notebook

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this answer has already been decided. You can look the answer M. Doosti Lakhani